# Spring Boot-Docker Can't See Logs Of Code

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have a basic Spring Boot app and I can't see any of the System.out.println values on my Docker container logs (methods work)
Here is the code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Value("${selenium.url}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${selenium.me}")
    private String name;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(WebDriver webDriver) {
        this.webDriver = webDriver;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<User> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println("creating");
        User created = userService.save(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(created, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{username}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUserByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println("hello, "+ name );
        User user = userService.getByUsername(username);
        if (user != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Actually I was trying to see if "selenium.url" value has changed because I declare it again in docker-compose.yml but I can't even just see basic sysout. What should I do?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ./target/elasticSpring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar elasticSpring.jar
ENTRYPOINT [ "java","-jar","/elasticSpring.jar" ]
```

And I'm not sure if it's needed but here is my compose:

```
version: '1'
services:
  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.12
    container_name: es
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    networks:
      - mynet

  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
    container_name: chrome
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    networks:
      - mynet

  springboot-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: springElastic
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - spring.elasticsearch.uris=es:9200
      - spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=es:9200
      - selenium.url=chrome:4444/wd/hub
    depends_on:
      - es
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: How are you trying to view the logs? Try `docker compose logs -f springboot-app`

Comment: I view them from Docker desktop-Logs